# How to ignore unexpected fields in JAX-RS 2.0 client?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs

I am developing a REST client that requests data from third party APIs.
These APIs change and sometimes add new fields.

Using *Jackson*, it is possible to use the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation, but I prefer to follow standards.

Is it possible do the same using *JAX-RS* 2.0?

Comment: The equivalent of Jackson for Java EE is JSON-P (JSON Parser).  There is no JSON Binding yet.  JAX-RS does not define JSON serialization, but you can implement your own using JSON-P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Using Jackson, it is possible to use @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation,
>   but I prefer to follow standards.

### Java EE 7 ([JSR-342](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=342))

As of Java EE 7 there isn't a standard JSON-Binding API.  However you can use JAX-RS with the Java API for JSON Processing (see: [JSR-353](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353))

- https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/consuming_and_producing_json_using

### Java EE 8 ([JSR-366](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=366))

A standard JSON-binding API will be developed as part of Java EE 8 (see:  [JSR-367](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367)).  Java EE 8 will also include an updated JAX-RS specification (see:  [JSR-370](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=370)) that will leverage JSR-367.